# Tryin to do ping to several pc with python. .

Tags: python, python-3.x, subprocess, ping

I'm trying to read a file which contains the ips of 300 computers an then writing in a new file if exists or not each one.

```
import os
import datetime
import platform
import subprocess

date = datetime.datetime.now()
day = date.day
hour = date.hour

os.chdir ('Path')
openips = open ("ips.txt","r")
ipfile = openips.readlines()
print (ipfile)

for ips in ipfile():
    ips = ips.strip()
    print (ips)
    args = ["ping", "-n", "4", "-l", "1", "-w", "1000", ips]
    pping = subprocess.Popen(args, stdout = subprocess.PIPE, stderr = subprocess.PIPE)
    for line in pping.stdout:
        print (line)
    os.chdir ('Path')
    presult = open ("pingresults_{}_{}.txt".format(day,hour), 'a')
    presult.write ('{}_{}\n'.format(ips, line))
    presult.close ()
```

Dunno why, everytime I'm testing my code. . . the result is:

> TypeError: 'list' object is not callable

I've tried everything, even when I change the variable to string . . . say the same, just changing the list for string

Comment: You need to provide the full traceback in your question (not just the final error).

Comment: Also use standard tcp or udp connection built in to python instead of "ping" which is a very very slow program testing on port 0 (which can be closed). Also spawn a thread for each connection test as there will be a lot of "wait" time that your program can do without.

Comment: @thebjorn So sorry, the next time I'll write all the traceback

Comment: @ege Thanks for your suggest, I'll think about. . . the true it's I just wanna know if the equip is alive (like true or false), doesn't care about anything else. But again, thanks, I'll consider use tcp or udp.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change:

```
for ips in ipfile:
   ...
```

no brackets

Comment: ¡Thanks! :)

Just one more question . . . what's the difference between this for and the normal one? Why in this case I shouldn't use it?

Again, thanks a lot . . . I'm new in this.

Comment: `xxx()` is calling the method. `xxx` is using the value of the variable.